# What's the meaning of と in 「『・・・・・・』っていう文章だと良かった」?

Tags: meaning, particle-と, conditionals

Can someone explain what と means in this sentence:

> 『・・・・・・』っていう文章だ**と**良かった

Answer (score 3):

> 『・・・・・・』っていう[文章]{ぶんしょう}だ**と**[良]{よ}かった

The と is a conjunctive particle that, in this case, tells us that some sort of judgement will follow it based on supposition or hypothesis.

Judgement: 良かった

Hypothesis: 『・・・』っていう文書だと

"If the phrase (or sentence) had been '・・・・', it would have been better (or great)."